# Issue with accessing css from build file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, build, gruntjs, kraken.js

I am having an issue where my grunt build file is building correctly, but the website I'm working on is not getting all of the css files.  It is only getting the master.css file.  I'm using nodejs, with kraken, on top of express.  I can't tell if there is some configuration option I need to change, I don't really know where I would do that.

Comment: Which CSS library are you using?

Is this a Kraken app built with the generator?

What grunt tasks do you have loaded?

Comment: I'm using LESS, it is built with the generator, and the grunt tasks I have loaded are build, less, copyto, requirejs, automation, automationci, concat, uglify, jshint... I think it's possible that this is an issue from us switching from angular to backbone w/ dust... which is still a config issue though.

Comment: When you say your website is not getting all css files do you mean they are not part of the resources? Are your <link> tags getting appended automatically or are you using express.static middleware?

Comment: yeah, it wasn't getting all of the resources, it was a combo of me having a typo in my partial to add CSS, and that the CSS wasn't getting copy-to'd the right folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the issue was with the changing structure of the project.  Going from angular to a dustjs w/ backbone combo changes the project form a SPA structure to a multi-page structure.  This makes a huge difference because now instead of sending everything at once we are sending pages as they are needed, this also means that when a user switches to a different view, the server will be building an html version of that view and sending it back as fully fleshed out html.  When the server builds the page it has access to the file structure, which means that the build folder that was necessary for the angular project, is no longer necessary.